# int.Parse on negative number results in exception

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, xamarin

This line of code:

```
int.Parse("-1");
```

Results in a FormatException that says "Input string was not in the correct format" when i run it on a device. On the emulator it works just fine. I've tested this with a bunch of devices, and the only one that is working as intended (i.e. returns an int with value -1) is the Samsung Galaxy Nexus, running android 4.2.1. All these devices generates an exception:

- Google Nexus 7 (4.3)
- Samsung S3 (4.1.2)
- Samsung Galaxy Tab (4.0.4)
- LG P970 (2.2.2)
- HTC Sensation (2.3.4)

I also tried to download the app [C#Shell](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=animaonline.cshell.free&hl=en) from playstore on a device, and enter the line above, the result is the same:

[image: C#Shell screenshot]

Do anyone know why this happens, or what can be done to resolve this issue?

**Update:**

The reason i'm investigating this issue is because our app is requesting a JSON from our servers, and it contains a bunch of negative numbers. We then use [ServiceStack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text) to parse the JSON, which results in all negative numbers becoming 0. ServiceStack has no way of setting a FormatSpecifier.

`int.Parse("-1", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` seems to work as intended on all devices regardless of what language they are using, but `int.Parse("-1", new CultureInfo("sv-SE"))` does not.

I find this a bit odd, since `int.Parse("-1", new CultureInfo("sv-SE"))` works on other platforms where we're not using xamarin or mono.

Comment: does providing a FormatSpecifier change the behavior?  I would file a bug with Xamarin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up committing a fix to ServiceStack:

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/pull/365

**Update:**

And now Xamarin also fixed it:

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=14185

Answer (score 0):

For any future readers if you are using other language than english and wondering how to do it, here is the code:

```
// Assuming that Err Code 1 is Success.

if (int.TryParse("-1", NumberStyles.Integer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out int errCode) && errCode == 1)
{
    return "Success";
}
else
{
    return "Err Msg";
}
```

This is a culture issue, as mentioned in this [github post](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/40258#issuecomment-667942032)

Some cultures uses a slightly different negative sign.
If you change the culture to CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, the parse works.